# Universal Approximation Theorems for Sparse Networks

Tags: functional-analysis, neural-networks, sparse-matrices

It is well-known, as shown in Hornik's papers, that feed-forward neural networks are dense in the spaces of continuous functions (uniformly on compacts) and the spaces of $L^p$ functions (for suitable measures, $p$).

However, are there any *proven* universal approximation results for sparse neural network architectures?

Comment: What is the precise definition for "sparse" that you are using here?

Comment: This is part of the question, since I've only heard the term being used loosely.  

But in my mind this means that each matrix in the network's representation has "most" of its entries equal to $0$.

Comment: @ProbablyAHuman: Well, you can always achieve this by augmenting the network with a lot of "unused, unnecessary" neurons. There is a recent theorem which considers the density of neural networks with bounded width (number of neurons per layer), but with the depth growing deeper and deeper. If you are interested in this, I can try to dig up the arXiv link. Also note that you always (except for very special activation functions) have to make the networks more and more complex (total number of neurons) to get universality.

Comment: But this result is for ReLu networks no?  Also, sparse for me should mean that somehow there is no reduncancy